# Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript error in Google Tag Manager with FB Bot

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-chatbot

I'm trying to put the following Facebook bot code into Google Tag Manager but am getting the "Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template." error. Any idea why?

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution="setup_tool"
  page_id="1393263590925062">
</div>
```

Comment: The "why" is that Google does not consider "attribution" and "page_id" to be valid attributes for a div element. Since the implied question is "how do I make this work" this is not a sufficient answer, though (I assume simply removing the attributes will break the Facebook script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GTM does not allow non-standard HTML attributes. Hence "`attribution`" and "`page_id`" in the HTML element will cause GTM throw error.

You can use Javascript to generate the chat code. Tested and it works.

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'fb-customerchat';
    el.setAttribute('page_id', '{{Constant - Facebook Page ID}}');
    el.setAttribute('attribution', 'setup_tool');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  })();
</script>
```

p/s: You can replace the variable `{{Constant - Facebook Page ID}}` with the page ID. It is best practice to use user-defined constant variables, read [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164390?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm

Comment: great thank you! Not sure who's fault this is more FB or Google tag manager, but I'm thinking Google because the tag says "custom JS/HTML" and it being valid or not is kinda non of their business

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding `data-` in front of each custom attribute also works (though I don't see it documented anywhere).

```html
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  data-attribution="setup_tool"
  data-page_id="1393263590925062">
</div>
```