# HTML code invalid. How can I add facebook messenger code with google tag manager?

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, messenger

Here's a code that I got from facebook chat plugin messenger.

```js
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="my-page-ID">
</div>
```

Google Tag manager send me an alert, that this code is invalid.
What should I do with this?

How can I add this code with Google tag manager?

Comment: Is “invalid” all it has to say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript error in Google Tag Manager with FB Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566247/invalid-html-css-or-javascript-error-in-google-tag-manager-with-fb-bot)